# I'm getting read access violation while deleting pointer

Tags: c++, mfc

```
C03View::~C03View()
{

    delete pBrush_;//this causes read access violation.  
}
```

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   this->pBrush_-> was
>   0xDDDDDDDD.

There is only one place in my code where I initialize this object:

```
void C03View::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CScrollView::OnInitialUpdate();
    pRenderTarget_ = GetRenderTarget();
    pBrush_ = new CD2DSolidColorBrush(GetRenderTarget(),   
                                           D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Blue));
}
```

This project is a MFC project.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: It could be overwritten by an unrelated overflow (it happens in some code I've seen). Set a watchpoint on pBrush_ to detect who changes its value.

Comment: Are you sure you don't `delete pBrush_` elsewhere in your code? The bit pattern `0xDDDDDDDD` is used by VS to mark memory that has been deallocated.

Comment: @BlackDwarf definitely it is not deleted anywhere else. The code is just a small starting project, so I can really be sure.

Comment: @LucaPizzamiglio how do you set watchpoint in VS? Do you mean breakpoint?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando in the breakpoint panel of VS should be possible to set watchpoint, a kind of breakpoint, that breaks the execution if the value of a specific memory area changes

Answer (score 3):

Possible scenarios:

1. the `pBrusch_` was not initialized while constructing C03View and never allocated (the OnInitialUpdate was never called out)
2. the `pBrusch_` was overwriten due to i.e. a memory corruption
3. The `pBrusch_` was already deleted before but was not set to NULL afterwards
4. The `pBrusch_` crashes in its own destructor
5. The object of `C03View` is corrupted or not allocated but the destructor is invoked
   ...